# How to render HTML stored inside an object?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, rendering, mern

I am using nextjs. I need to render custom landing pages according to their specific url. I am able to render all the details from the database of that particular URL except for the object which contains the details for the page. The pages has been built with the help of grapesjs.
Following is the data in db:
[image]

Following is code for rendering the list of the pages:
index.js

```
import Link from "next/link"
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/webpage/");
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }
  };
};

const blog = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data?.map((currentElement) => {
        return (
          <div key={currentElement.id} className="ssr-styles">
            <h3>
              {/* {currentElement._id} */}
              <Link href={`/blog/${currentElement.url}`}>
                {currentElement.name}
              </Link>
            </h3>
          </div> 
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default blog;
```

Following is the code where the page is actually rendering:
[pageno].js=>

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/webpage/");
  const data = await res.json();
  const paths = data.map((currentElement) => {
    return {
      params: { pageno: currentElement.url.toString() }
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  };
};
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const url = context.params.pageno;
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/webpage/url/${url}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  };
};

export const Details = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={data.url} className="ssr-styles">
        {data._id}
        <h3>{data.name}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

how do I render the html inside the object content so as to get a proper webpage?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) library. it converts an HTML string to React elements.